Access Denied (HTTP ERROR 403) When Trying to Stream Audio Using ytdl-core in Node.js
I'm working on a project where I need to stream audio from YouTube using ytdl-core in a Node.js application. I have a function that fetches the video URL based on the song and artist name, and another function that attempts to stream the audio. However, I'm encountering an issue where I get an "Access Denied" error (HTTP ERROR 403) when trying to stream or download the audio.
`const sanitizeFilename = (name) => {
  return name.replace(/[\\/*?:"<>|]/g, "");
};

const getVideoUrl = async (songName, artistName) => {
  songName = sanitizeFilename(songName);
  artistName = sanitizeFilename(artistName);

  const query = `${songName} ${artistName} audio`;

  try {
    const searchResults = await ytsr(query, { limit: 1 });
    console.log(searchResults.items);

    if (searchResults.items.length === 0) {
      return { error: 'No results found' };
    }

    const firstItem = searchResults.items[0];
    if (!firstItem || !firstItem.id) {
      return { error: 'Invalid search result item' };
    }

    const videoId = firstItem.id;
    return { status: 'success', video_id: videoId };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: `Failed to fetch video URL: ${error.message}` };
  }
};

const streamAudioFunction = async (req, res) => {
  const videoId = req.params.video_id;
  const trackName = decodeURIComponent(req.params.trackName);
  const artistName = decodeURIComponent(req.params.artistName);
  const trackGenre = decodeURIComponent(req.params.trackGenre);

  console.log({ videoId, trackName, artistName, trackGenre });
  const url = `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`;

  try {
    const info = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
    const format = ytdl.chooseFormat(info.formats, { quality: 'highestaudio' });

    // Assuming the activity record is created here
    const activityRecord = await Activity.create({ songName: trackName, artistName: artistName, songGenre: trackGenre });
    res.redirect(format.url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error streaming audio:', error.message);
    res.json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

Whenever I hit the download or stream endpoint, I receive the following error message in the browser:

Access to rr1---sn-pqx5jxaa0a5g-2o96.googlevideo.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

I've verified that the video ID is correct and that the URL is properly formed. Additionally, I am using a MacBook Air M2 and have turned off the Apple AirPlay receiver. What could be causing this access denied issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be appreciated!

The problem is likely to be from the player base.js file configuration which has changed. Therefore, you'll need to decipher the url with the new base.js file for it to work well.

I did not get u , there is not file named base.js

The problem is not even from the base.js file that's being generated when the video starts playing. Well, let me tell you all what i have tried:

I have tried the first step i mentioned previously, but it didn't work.


Distube library didn't work too even with cookies and proxies.


I tried to change the url params values but it didn't work.

The best step is to use YouTube internal api. But I'm still trying to get around them

For me, the Distube library works fine and got endorsed by the original ytdl-core in August. Are you sure it's malfunctioning?
